# I have connected my MVC3 application to a MySQl database. I can get an entire table into m3

Tags: c#, mysql

I have connected my C# MVC3 application to a MySQL database. I can get an entire table into my application. But I only need specific data through queries. How Do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Entity Framework. https://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.3.1